# UISearchBar: Predictive Search ReloadData crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, grand-central-dispatch

In my app I've a `searchbar` to search 3 different type of items. These 3 items have different data sources so on each text change I've to send 3 diffrent network requests. I show these 3 type of items in 3 different sections in `UITableView`. When response of any request is received I update the data source and call `tableView.reloadData`. An example function to get one item (User) can be seen below:-

```
func searchUsers(withName name: String) {
        showNetworkActivity()
        UserService.search(query: name) { (data, error) in
            Queue.Main.execute({
                self.hideNetworkActivity()
                if error == nil {
                    self.searchedUsers = data as! [User]
                } else {
                    self.searchedUsers = []
                }
                self.searchTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
}
```

But randomly my App is crashed due to **index out of bound exception**. The crash happens when new data is arrived but tableview is busy in reloading according to previously received data. I tried reloading only related section instead of reloading whole table but it causes more crashes. How can I avoid such crashes?

*PS: Queue.Main ensures that all the things are being done on Main thread.*

Comment: a simple cause might be confusion on the part of your data source as to which array to use.  e.g. your numberOfRowsInSection reports the length of the search result, but your cellForRowAtIndexPath checks a row offset in your regular model (the non-searchUsers array that it normally uses)

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue. I only have one data source as Array.